# Android Studio error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started running Android Studio and I am stuck with the below error, how can I resolve this?

```
Error: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\codecanyon-17413949-android-rewards-app-pocket\android-rewards-app-pocket 1.4\Pocket v1.4\Android Project - v1.4\Pocket\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\mediarouter-v7\24.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_media_route_on_19_light.png into C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\codecanyon-17413949-android-rewards-app-pocket\android-rewards-app-pocket 1.4\Pocket v1.4\Android Project - v1.4\Pocket\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_media_route_on_19_light.png
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Failed to crunch file C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\codecanyon-17413949-android-rewards-app-pocket\android-rewards-app-pocket 1.4\Pocket v1.4\Android Project - v1.4\Pocket\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\mediarouter-v7\24.0.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_media_route_on_19_light.png into C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\codecanyon-17413949-android-rewards-app-pocket\android-rewards-app-pocket 1.4\Pocket v1.4\Android Project - v1.4\Pocket\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\ic_media_route_on_19_light.png

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 9.687 secs
```

Comment: Try to move your project on desktop and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to crunch file means Android Studio is not able to process the file. It is too long and it has reached the maximum file path line of the operating system.

To solve the issue move your project to a shorter path. For example:

```
C:\your_project_folder
```